# is there a way to workaround ''recursion depth reach in comparison'' in parallelizing a loop within a loop?

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing

**What is the problem about**:

I am building an agent-based model with mesa & networkx in python. In one line, the model tries to model how changes in an agent's attitude can influence whether or not they take the decision to adopt a new technology. I m currently attempting to parallelize a part of it, to speed up run time. The number of agents currently are 4000. I keep hitting the error message as follows:

*'if i < 256
Recursion depth reached in comparison'*

The pseudo-code below outlines the process (**after which I explain what I've tried and failed**).

1. Initializes a model of 4000 agents
2. Gives each agent a set of agents to interact with at every time step at two levels: a) geographic neighbhours, b) 3 social circles.
3. From each interaction pair in the list, agents' attitudes are compared, some modifications to attitudes are made.
4. This process repeats for several time-steps, with results of one step carrying over to another.

```
import pandas as pd 
import multiprocessing as mp 
import dill 
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool 

def model_initialization():
    df = pd.read_csv(path+'4000_household_agents.csv')
    for agent in df:
        model.schedule.add(agent)

        #assign three circles of influence 
        agent.social_circle1 = social_circle1
        agent.social_circle2 = social_circle2
        agent.social_circle3 = social_circle3


def assign_interactions():
    for agent in schedule.agents:
        #geograhic neighbhours 
        neighbours = agent.get_neighbhours()
        interaction_list.append(agent,neighbhour)

        #interaction in circles of influence
        interaction_list.append(agent, social_circle1)
        interaction_list.append(agent, social_circle2)
        interaction_list.append(agent, social_circle3)

        return interaction_list

def attitude_change(agent1,agent2):
    #compare attitudes
    if agent1.attitude > agent2.attitude:
        # make some change to attitudes
        agent1.attitude -= 0.2
        agent2.attitude += 0.2 
    return agent1.attitude,agent2.attitude

def interactions(interaction):
        agent1 = interaction[0]
        agent2 = interaction[1]

        agent1.attitude,agent2.attitude = attitude_change(agent1,agent2)


def main():
    model_initialization()
    interaction_list=  assign_interactions()

    #pool = mp.Pool(10)
    pool = ProcessingPool(10)

    #interaction list can have over and above 89,000 interactions atleast 
    results = pool.map(interactions, [interaction for interaction in interaction_list])

# run this process several times 
for i in range(12):
    main()
```

**What I've tried**

1. Because the model step is sequential, the only part I can parallelize is the *interactions( )* function. Because I thought the interaction loop is called more 90,000 times, I reset the sys.setrecursionlimit( ) to about 100,000.  Fails.
2. I have broken the *interactions_list* to several chunks of 500 each and pooled the processes for each chunk. Same error.
3. To see  if something was absolutely wrong, I only took the first 35  elements (a small number) of the interactions list and only ran that. It still hits recursion depth.

Can anyone help me see which part of the code hits recursion depth? I tried both dill + multiprocessing as well as multiprocessing alone. The latter gives 'pickling error'.

Comment: What's the exact error message and corresponding code, please? The code you posted doesn't look like it should be doing recursion at all; it may be some typo or similar...

Comment: Questions tagged with `multiprocesing` should also be tagged with the platform on which you are running, such as `windows` or `linux`.  In function `assign_interactions`, I don't see where `interaction_list` is defined. Also, can't `[interaction for interaction in interaction_list]` be simplified to `interaction_list`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Indeed the interaction loop can be simplified to just 'interaction'. I tried multiple workarounds, but because the loop is still sequential to some extent, there is no effective way to parallelize the code. My solution to this was to divide the agents themselves into different files and run the model parallelly for these agent-sets.